# Como pegar o numero da coluna da tabela em que está um input que estou escrevendo?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho inputs text em celulas de uma tabela.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Bola</td>
        <td>Casa</td>
        <td>Arvore</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" class='campo' /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class='campo' /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class='campo' /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Quando digito em um deles quero saber se ele esta na coluna 1, 2 ou 3. Como conseguir isso?

```
$(".campo").on("input", function(){
    // ?????        
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

você pode transformar a sua coleção de inputs em uma lista, então olhar o indice do input dentro desta lista:

```js
var campos = document.querySelectorAll(".campo");
var colunaAtual = document.getElementById("colunaAtual");

//converter coleção de elementos em array.
campos = [].slice.apply(campos);

var onCampoClick = function () {
  colunaAtual.textContent = campos.indexOf(this) + 1;
}

campos.forEach(function (campo) {
  campo.addEventListener("input", onCampoClick);
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Bola</td>
    <td>Casa</td>
    <td>Arvore</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" class='campo' /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class='campo' /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class='campo' /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
Coluna Atual: <span id="colunaAtual" type="number"></span>
```

caso queira fazer com jQuery:

```js
var campos = $(".campo");
var colunaAtual = $("#colunaAtual");

//converter coleção de elementos em array.
campos = [].slice.apply(campos);

$(document).on("input", campos, function (event) {
  colunaAtual.html(campos.indexOf(event.target) + 1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Bola</td>
    <td>Casa</td>
    <td>Arvore</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" class='campo' /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class='campo' /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class='campo' /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
Coluna Atual: <span id="colunaAtual" type="number"></span>
```

Comment: oO, ficou bacana.

Comment: @JoaoPaulo, mas o ideal é usar um data-* para mapear a tabela

Answer (score 3):

Use o `parent` ou `closest`.

Veja com `parent`.

```
$(".campo").on("focus", function ()
{
    var $td = $(this).parent();    
    console.log($td.index()); //index
})
```

Veja com `closest`

```
$(".campo").on("focus", function ()
{
    var $td = $(this).closest('td');    

    console.log($td.index()); //index
})
```

Dentre esses dois, prefiro utilizar o `closest('td')`, pois se eu colocasse o `input` dentro de uma `div`, mesmo estando dentro desta, ele ainda continuaria pegando o `td` - diferentemente ao `parent`, que pegaria a `div`

O `index()`, por sua vez, serve para capturar a posição do elemento no `DOM`, que seria contado a partir da posição `0` (o primeiro elemento).

Veja isso funcionando no [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ksLf0vnr/)

Answer (score -2):

Ou você cria uma propriedade no elemento ou pode aplicar uma lógica com base no código abaixo:

```
var tr = document.createElement('tr'),
    td = document.createElement('td');

tr.appendChild(td); // Simulação de um <tr><td></td></tr>

Array.prototype.indexOf.call(tr.childNodes, td); // Retorna a posição do td, no caso, retorna 0. (-1 = Não achou)
```

Comment: A partir de qual momento você pega o  `td` através da ação feita no `input`?